# Setting up XML coding for website

Tags: html, xml, magento, ftp, content-management-system

I don't have any experience when it comes to coding any type of language, but I do want to try and understand the logic flow. For my website, I am using magento as the backend system and trying to create a blogging page on my site. I have third party developer working for me, but they gave me an estimate that doesn't seem right. In the backend, I can create he CMS page for blog, but I want to design the template or even buy a template off a free lancer. Only thing is that there seems to be two method to design the blog and that is either manually typing in the Xml coding for the page layout or select the xml file from within my server. I don't have admin access to my server because I left that for my developers to work on, but I do have the ftp access. I'm honestly not sure if the ftp is my actual server access or not. To make things short I have two question. First is that is it possible to simply copy and paste the xml coding into the page layout? The other question is if I were to download the xml document, would I simply upload it via ftp access and choose that template on magento backend?

Answer (score 0):

Developing a Magento page involves significantly more work than dropping some XML into a Magento CMS page. You need to code the relevant HTML and CSS, put it into the correct files (.phtml template files for the HTML, .css stylesheets for the CSS), and then reference it correctly via the layout XML or through other means.

So, to answer your questions:

> First is that is it possible to simply copy and paste the xml coding into the page layout?

Yes, you can copy and paste layout XML into a CMS page. However, XML layout configuration is only a small piece of building a page.

> The other question is if I were to download the xml document, would I simply upload it via ftp access and choose that template on magento backend?

There's a lot more to it than uploading an XML document. As I said above, you have to think about the HTML and CSS files, ensuring they are integrated correctly within Magento's structure.